# Alert an array value that results from an AJAX call

Tags: ajax, google-maps, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I am having some difficulty trying to alert a value which is the result of an ajax call.  The code below is working to the extent that `grid.onClick` will alert the value of `row`, but for the life of me I cannot figure out how to alert the value of latitude and/or longitude.

```
function showGridSalesResult(){
var data = [];
var r_from = $('#min_val').val();
var r_to = $('#max_val').val();
var p_from = $('#from_year').val();
var p_to = $('#to_year').val();
var type = $('#sf3').val();
var municipality = $('#SaleCity').val();

$(document).ready(function(){
jqXHR = $.ajax({
    url: sURL + "search/ajaxSearchResult",
    type: "POST",
    data: 'r_from='+r_from+'&r_to='+r_to+'&p_from='+p_from+'&p_to='+p_to+'&type='+type+'&up_limit='+up_limit+'&low_limit='+low_limit+'&municipality='+municipality,
    dataType: 'json', 
    success: function(json){
        $.each(json, function(i,row){ 
            data[i] = {
                address: row.Address,
                municipality: row.Municipality,
                geoencoded: row.geoencoded,
                latitude: parseFloat(row.geolat),
                longitude: parseFloat(row.geolong)
            };                            
        });

        grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGridMap", data, columns, options);
        grid.invalidate();
        grid.render();
        grid.resizeCanvas();                
        grid.onClick = function (e, row, cell){
            alert(row); // THIS WORKS
            alert(data[row].latitude); // THIS DOES NOT WORK
        }                             
        setMarkers(map, data);
    }    
  });
});
}
```

Can someone please help me to figure out how I can alert the latitude and longitude values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the documentation : 
https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/Slick.Grid#wiki-getCellFromEvent

you should use :

```
var cell = grid.getCellFromEvent(e);
var latitude = data[cell.row].latitude;
alert(latitude);
```